# Keylogger for android

Tags: keyboard

I'm in the process of moving from qwerty to another layout on my computers, and most other layouts are focused on the use of the home row. I also keylog myself to find out what layout would work best for me, with my usage pattern. (And it's a great backup if the program you're writing in crashes.)

Now I want to do the same on android. Home row isn't really a thing when you're typing with your thumbs, so I thought I'd make a new layout designed for thumbs, rather than hands. Step one is to figure out what I normally write, so a keylogger would work great. Then I can build markov-chains, do benchmarks and everything would be great.

Is that available, or do I have to write my own keyboard app that just does that?

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score 1):

These are availabe for `free` use :

KidLogger ([Download Page](http://kidlogger.net/download.html))

or `Xposed` :

[Use a Keylogger to Record What Friends Do on Your Android](http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/use-keylogger-record-what-friends-do-your-android-0157269/)